# Getting Incorrect results for selecting values between 2 dates

Tags: database, oracle, sql

I am trying to run the below query to select some results between 2 dates but I am getting results as the condition doesn't exist. So what is wrong here?

```
select OPEN_TIME, STATUS 
from PROBSUMMARY 
where trunc (open_time) >= '01-01-2020' 
  and trunc (open_time) < '01-01-2021'
```

Comment: What is the `open_time` column data type; and what is the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` in your session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing dates with strings; <strike>the dates are converted to strings to do that comparison. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694):</strike>

> During `SELECT FROM` operations, Oracle converts the data from the column to the type of the target variable.

When your dates are implicitly converted to strings, they all fall within that range of string values, based on the [character value comparison rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C).

The above isn't true of course; this supersedes it:

> When comparing a character value with a `DATE` value, Oracle converts the character data to `DATE`.

So something odd is happening in that implicit conversion, which will depend on your `NLS_DATE_FOPRMAT` setting. Anyway, the following advice still stands...

Compare dates with dates instead, either converting your strings with `to_date()` or with date literals:

```
where open_time >= date '2020-01-01' and open_time < date '2021-01-01'
```

You don't need to truncate the dates back to midnight; which will help with being able to use an index, if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine now with to_date()

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```sql
SELECT OPEN_TIME, STATUS
FROM PROBSUMMARY
WHERE OPEN_TIME < '01-01-2020' AND OPEN_TIME > '01-01-2021';
```

Above where condition start_date include date but the end_date doesn't include, for include both date you have to go with `=`.

Make sure your passing date must follow the syntax of mysql.

Comment: _"Make sure your passing date must follow the syntax of mysql."_    Why mysql?  The op did not tag mysql, he tagged oracle. And nothing in his statement suggests that mysql is involved at all.

Comment: If you are using date field datatype date then oracle uses 'YYYY/MM/DD' formate so you have to pass value like OPEN_TIME < '2020/01/01' or OPEN_TIME > '2021/01/01'

Comment: _"If you are using date field datatype date then oracle uses 'YYYY/MM/DD' formate "_   Incorrect.  If your are using DATE datatype, then those dares are in oracle's internal, binary "format".  'YYYY/MM/DD' is just one of many possible _character representations_ of a date.  Once you say "<fill in the blank> format" you are dealing with character strings, not dates.   And again, why the reference to mysql when the OP made no such connection.